# Do I need these packages on Ubuntu KDE?

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, kde, plasma

Recently I have installed the package `kubuntu-desktop`. Then I came to know that there is anotheer similiar package `kde-standard` which will install the following new packages:

```
 accountwizard akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator dragonplayer juk
  kaddressbook kde-baseapps kde-config-mailtransport kde-plasma-desktop kde-standard
  kdepim-addons kdepim-runtime kdepim-themeeditors kf5-kdepim-apps-libs-data
  kf5-messagelib-data kio-ldap kio-sieve kmail kmailtransport-akonadi knotes kopete
  kopete-data korganizer ktnef kwrite libbctoolbox1 libbzrtp0 libgadu3
  libgrantlee-textdocument5 libkf5akonadi-data libkf5akonadiagentbase5
  libkf5akonadicalendar-data libkf5akonadicalendar5abi2 libkf5akonadicontact-data
  libkf5akonadicontact5abi1 libkf5akonadicore-bin libkf5akonadicore5abi2
  libkf5akonadimime-data libkf5akonadimime5 libkf5akonadinotes-data
  libkf5akonadinotes5 libkf5akonadiprivate5abi2 libkf5akonadisearch-bin
  libkf5akonadisearch-data libkf5akonadisearch-plugins libkf5akonadisearchcore5
  libkf5akonadisearchdebug5 libkf5akonadisearchpim5 libkf5akonadisearchxapian5
  libkf5akonadiwidgets5abi1 libkf5alarmcalendar-data libkf5alarmcalendar5abi2
  libkf5calendarcore5abi2 libkf5calendarsupport-data libkf5calendarsupport5abi1
  libkf5calendarutils-bin libkf5calendarutils-data libkf5calendarutils5abi1
  libkf5contacteditor5 libkf5eventviews-data libkf5eventviews5abi1
  libkf5followupreminder5 libkf5grantleetheme-data libkf5grantleetheme-plugins
  libkf5grantleetheme5 libkf5gravatar-data libkf5gravatar5abi2
  libkf5identitymanagement-data libkf5identitymanagement5abi1 libkf5imap-data
  libkf5imap5 libkf5incidenceeditor-bin libkf5incidenceeditor-data
  libkf5incidenceeditor5abi2 libkf5kaddressbookgrantlee5
  libkf5kaddressbookimportexport5 libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5 libkf5kmanagesieve5
  libkf5kontactinterface-data libkf5kontactinterface5 libkf5ksieve-data libkf5ksieve5
  libkf5ksieveui5 libkf5ldap-data libkf5ldap5abi1 libkf5libkdepim-data
  libkf5libkdepim-plugins libkf5libkdepim5abi2 libkf5libkdepimakonadi5
  libkf5libkleo5abi1 libkf5mailcommon-plugins libkf5mailcommon5abi4
  libkf5mailimporter-data libkf5mailimporter5abi1 libkf5mailimporterakonadi5
  libkf5mailtransport-data libkf5mailtransport5abi2 libkf5mailtransportakonadi5
  libkf5mbox5 libkf5messagecomposer5abi2 libkf5messagecore5abi2 libkf5messagelist5abi1
  libkf5messageviewer-plugins libkf5messageviewer5abi5 libkf5mime-data libkf5mime5abi2
  libkf5mimetreeparser5abi3 libkf5pimcommon-plugins libkf5pimcommon5abi3
  libkf5pimcommonakonadi5 libkf5pimtextedit-data libkf5pimtextedit5abi3
  libkf5sendlater5 libkf5templateparser5abi2 libkf5tnef-data libkf5tnef5
  libkf5webengineviewer5abi3 libkgantt2 libkgantt2-l10n libkolabxml1v5 libkopete1
  libkpimgapi-data libkpimgapicalendar5 libkpimgapicontacts5 libkpimgapicore5abi1
  libkpimgapitasks5 libkpimimportwizard5 libkpimitinerary-data libkpimitinerary5
  libkpimkdav-data libkpimkdav5abi2 libkpimpkpass5 libkpimsmtp5abi1
  libmediastreamer-base10 libmediastreamer-voip10 libortp13 libotr5 libprotobuf-c1
  libqgpgme7 libqt5networkauth5 libsasl2-modules-kdexoauth2 libturbojpeg
  libxerces-c3.2 libzxingcore1 mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-common
  mariadb-server-core-10.3 mbox-importer pim-data-exporter pim-sieve-editor sweeper
```

Do I really need these packages to have a smooth KDE Plasma experience on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, that's why `kde-standard` will install them. It's the KDE desktop, which will provide the "smooth kde plasma" you seek.

Comment: @waltinator it seems you have posted your answer in the comment section by mistake ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these are KDE PIM applications (akregator, kaddressbook, kmail, korganizer) and their dependencies. There are some other KDE apps (juk, dragonplayer, kwrite) in there as well. None of them are essential for running the Plasma desktop though